# How to combine select/update prepared statement?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Basically every 24th hour my script will choose 10 random images from table01 store the data in a seperate table02 which then will be avaliable to my users where they can vote these images.

After 24hours the script run again and should update table01 with the data from table02 and then truncate table02 choose 10 new pictures from table01 and store the data in table02 which then again will be avaliable for voting.

The prepared statement that choose the 10 random images

(This SQL is both INSERT and SELECT)

"Two sql in one so i dont have to store the data before i use it"

```
    $stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" INSERT INTO table02 "
    . " (rating_daily_views, rating_daily_votes, rating_daily_rating, " rating_daily_category, rating_daily_imgId) "
    . " SELECT views, votes, rating, category, id"
    . " FROM table01 "
    . " WHERE category IN (?) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $cat1);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```

Here is my two statements that i would looove to merge into one if possible?

Select statement

```
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare("SELECT rating_daily_views, rating_daily_votes, rating_daily_rating, rating_daily_imgId "
        . " FROM table02 ");
$stmt->execute();
```

Update statement

```
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" UPDATE table01 SET "
    . " views = ?, "
    . " votes = ?, "
    . " rating = ? "
    . " WHERE id = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $views, $votes, $rating, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the `UPDATE ... INNER JOIN` query which is supported in MySQL:

```sql
UPDATE table01 t1
INNER JOIN table02 t2 ON t1.id = t2.rating_daily_imgId
SET t1.views = t2.rating_daily_views, 
    t1.votes = t2.rating_daily_votes, 
    t1.rating = t2.rating_daily_rating
```

Comment: I actually began to do a while loop which i just now read is bad practice in this example... i will look into this, is there any reason you assign t1, t2? can this be anything and used as i want?

Comment: Indeed, those are table aliases to avoid writing full table name and can be anything.

Comment: Waow this actually worked and is really really simple and a really great example thanks aloooot

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.